# IOS UIWebview webkit and decidepolicyfornavigationaction error

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, webkit

iPad programming, IOS6.
Got a `(UIWebView *)`helpview object which loads in a bundled html file using

```
[helpView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

Loads successfully and in the html file there's a 
`<a href="didTap://touchme">here</a>` to enable and process hyperlink touches.

All works well, except that if I then launch a NSURLRequest to get an external website and then go back to the original html file, the anchor tags in the html file fail to work and I get this error:

> WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate:  setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil

I didn't think IOS programming uses webkit so why is this error appearing? and how do I restore the anchor tags?

Interestingly, it all works fine if I release and re-create the UIWebView object instead of using an IBOutlet and retaining it throughout.  But that created other problems with the UIWebview retain count which I can't figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a custom NSURLProtocol somewhere in your application? It may not even be registered in the same code that uses your UIWebView or it may be registered after the call to loadRequest: but, since the request loads asynchronously (I believe) it could still interfere. Search for `[NSURLProtocol registerClass` somewhere in your code, disable all of them and see if that fixes the problem. If it does, then the solution is likely to fix an exception in the custom protocol code.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error today on iOS 10.3. The same as you - I use UIWebView, not WKWebView. In my case the issue was caused by spaces at the end of loaded url.